# After learning one language, are other languages easier?

Tags: python

So I've always wanted to learn code/program since I was 14 or so. I took YouTube and even website tutorials for Java, tried to follow along and everything but just didn't get it. I thought that Java was the best and easiest language to learn for a beginner. Well, not for me.

Fast forward to the beginning of this school year, I'm in high school and 16. I started taking programming class and we're going to learn Python. A month or two later and I actually understand the syntax of it, how if-else statements work, variables, functions, I even programmed a function to solve my Physics homework.

Do you think now, that having a basic understanding of Python, it would be easier for me to learn another programming language like C, or Java, or something else?

Comment: Not necessarily. Learning 3 disparate languages will, but only a single language won't tell you more than you could already learn.

Comment: Yes. Similar concept comparing learning to eat an apple to learning to eat an orange. There are similarities of course, but the specific details and preferences are different

Answer (score 1):

Definitely, it certainly helped in my experience, where my first language was Liberty BASIC, and then Python. I found learning Python easier than learning LB. It's really more to with how you think about your programs, your logical thinking/problem solving skills.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a very high-quality question, but the answer is quite simple. Always yes.

The more languages you learn, the more you'll find similarities between them. It will eventually be a matter of applying different algorithms and data structures to get work done instead of choosing programming languages, for general purpose programming, anyway.

When you get into application-specific things, such as embedded programming (imagine, cars, planes, military), then "learning that specific language" will become inescapable and valuable as employable skills. Also, ancient languages such as COBOL apparently fetch a pretty penny.

Enjoy the life of computer science and/or software engineering, kid!

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely.
knowing one language always helps learning the new one, especially if they are similar. if you have learned python I'd suggest to move to java. avoid C or C++ they are very theoretics and much harder to learn with no stiff teacher and must-do homeworks..
be aware that python is much less strict than other languages so you will need to work a bit harder, but yeah do it, now! learning programming takes a little time and A LOT of practice but it sure no impossible.
I would suggest watching some wonderful online lectures on Udacity or Coursera.

Good luck ;)